# Cannot open Ubuntu installation LIveUSB in desktop

Tags: 18.04, reinstall, desktop-icons

After trying to solve a problem and failed, I decided to reinstall ubuntu 18.04.
But the desktop icons do not open either with the left double click or with the right button. The only thing that works is 'open with other applications'. My problem is that the Ubuntu installer located on the USB is only found on the desktop.
My question is:
is there any way to open the Ubuntu installer in another way?
Thank you kindly

Comment: Welcome! Did you follow [this guide](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick) to create USB? Did you [verify](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#1-overview) the ISO?

Comment: You must boot from the USB. You cannot launch the installer from some other OS session.

Comment: @user535733 The USBLive Ubuntu installer icon int the desktop does not open.How can i open it in another way?

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way for regular users to run the Ubuntu installer is to boot from the USB.

Trying to open the installer in an existing Ubuntu/Windows/Mac session simply won't work.

Shut down your machine and [boot from the USB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick#Booting_the_Computer_from_USB).

There are [advanced ways to install](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/#Installation_without_a_CD) without booting from a USB Installer, but those are highly technical and not advised for regular users.